# Ampscript - RSS & Enclosures

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, images

I'm trying to get the URL from the [enclosure tag in an RSS](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#element-channel-item-enclosure) to display in my email.

I referred to this [Retrieving images from RSS feed ExactTarget with AMPScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55532/retrieving-images-from-rss-feed-exacttarget-with-ampscript) but the RSS I'm using doesn't include the image in the description tag.

So if I were to use:

```
Set @image = Field(Row(@images,@cnt), "Value")
```

and display the output of this later, all I'm getting is

```
"
```

How can I extract the URL on a RSS enclosure?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "Value", you can use: "url_att" to include the image url.

Comment: Looks a fine answer to me.